# How to install package which was extracted into folder without building into deb file

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I'm extracting deb file into a folder with `dpkg-deb -R` command and changing postinst. When everything is done, I want to install this package by giving directory path instead of building deb package.

Is there any way to install package from extracted directory?

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you can and it is called Debian *Binary* package. Use:

  ```
  dpkg-deb -b|--build binary-directory [archive|directory]
  ```

  Example:

  ```
  dpkg-deb -b yourpackage-extracted-folder
  ```

  Reference: `man dpkg-deb`

  The build step should be quick only if special case with very large files in size or number. You may use these options: `-z0 --nocheck`
- There is other alternative tools like `equivs`, also may compress them with generic tools (`7z`) just watch for owner and permissions.
- If you looking direct install, you can copy the folders directly, skip only `DEBIAN`.

  However, this alone doesn't record the installation in `dpkg` system. So if you have another tool that checks this as dependency, it will fail. A workaround this is by installing an old copy of the package then overwrite its files by direct copy.

Comment: is this working without creating a package? Will this command `dpkg-deb -b` install directory content directly?

Comment: Thank you for quick answers but I need to install directly without building a new deb file. Because it's taking too much time in `docker build` phase. Extracting is fast but building a new deb file is taking long time. If I could install it directly from directory it'll be the best for me.

Comment: dz, it took 58 seconds. It's building in docker container (while building docker image). I'll check if `-z0 --no-check` reduce it.

Comment: @uzay95 I'm sure I have seen before here a question about how manually install deb. Still I couldn't find yet.

Comment: @uzay95 I updated the answer with manual install